# VBA Issue with Link break while Sheet Copy

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet which based on a given date and aircraft #, will produce a report and 3 graphs. As I have to report the status of all the Aircraft in a single report, I developed a procedure to loop through the aircraft numbers and after changing the aircraft number in my source worksheet, copies them to a new workbook. I am also moving charts from that sheet to another sheet of that new workbook and am doing some extra things.
 I need to cut the connection of new workbook/ worksheets from the source workbook. Otherwise, the name of graphs or other relative cells will read latest Aircraft number form that. I already added a line for breaking the connection, also I am removing all the names from new workbook, but still I can't really kill such a data connection. I tried looping through all the links and kill them after worksheet copy, but again not working.
  Right now my code is working and showing the correct information by using `NewWB.BreakLink ThisWorkbook.FullName, xlExcelLinks`, but the procedure is very unstable and always crashs. I tried to add the `application.wait` for one second, but again it crashes. However, when I am adding a toggle breakpoint at the loop and pressing `F5` constantly, it is working fine! Here is that section of code which I think is related. This code is running while the calculation is manual, event is not enabled and screen updating is off.

```
    For i = UBound(CurAC) To LBound(CurAC) Step -1
    If CurAC(i) = "" Then GoTo Skip
    WS.Cells(6, 2) = CurAC(i)
    DeleteCharts WSC
    ChartNew CLng(CurAC(i))
    WS.Calculate
    If WSC.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then WSC.ChartObjects(1).Chart.ChartArea.Copy

    Set NewWS = NewWB.Worksheets.Add
    With NewWS

        .Name = CurAC(i) & "Chart"
        .Activate
        .Range("a1").Select
        If WSC.ChartObjects.Count > 0 Then .Pictures.Paste
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        With .Shapes(1)
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = .Parent.Range("k1").Left

        End With
        WS.Copy NewWB.Sheets(1)
        ActiveSheet.Name = CurAC(i)
        Set ACWS = ActiveSheet
        NewWB.BreakLink ThisWorkbook.FullName, xlExcelLinks
        Set ChtOb = ACWS.ChartObjects(1)
        ChtOb.Top = .Range("a23").Top
        ChtOb.Width = 360
        ChtOb.Left = .Range("a23").Left
        ChtOb.Chart.Location xlLocationAsObject, .Name
        Set ChtOb = ACWS.ChartObjects(1)
        ChtOb.Top = .Range("i23").Top
        ChtOb.Width = 360
        ChtOb.Left = .Range("p23").Left - ChtOb.Width
        ChtOb.Chart.Location xlLocationAsObject, .Name
' third chart
        Set ChtOb = ACWS.ChartObjects(1)
        ChtOb.Top = .Range("k1").Top
        ChtOb.Width = 245
        ChtOb.Left = .Range("p1").Left - ChtOb.Width
        ChtOb.Chart.Location xlLocationAsObject, .Name

        With .PageSetup
            .PrintArea = "$A$1:$o$40" '.Range().Address
            .Orientation = xlLandscape
            .Zoom = False
            .FitToPagesTall = 1
            .FitToPagesWide = 1
            .LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
            .RightMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
            .TopMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.15)
            .BottomMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.15)
            .HeaderMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)
            .FooterMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(0.1)

        End With

    End With
    ACWS.Activate
Skip:

'    NewWB.Save
    Debug.Print CurAC(i); vbTab; Round(Timer - t, 1)
    Application.Wait Time + TimeValue("00:00:01")
    RemoveName NewWB
    NewWB.BreakLink ThisWorkbook.FullName, xlExcelLinks
Next
```

Comment: Can you create a new sheet in newwb and just put the values from ws into it?  Set wksNew =newwb.worksheets.add; wksNew.range(ws.usedrange.address).value = ws.usedrange.value. Then you won’t have to worry about links...

Comment: Hi, no I can't I need the format and shapes. I also have chart there. But I can do a step by step copy of value, format and shapes then charts. Not sure if that is a better way. Anyway, I also really interested to know how To deal with the issue.

Comment: What happens if you copy the sheet then copy the values?

Comment: @wallyeye Hi,  I will try, But I think as I have lots of Merged cells and also Charts and named ranges for dynamic charts, it will mess up my report, But I will check and let you know so If that was ok, you be able to add it as answer.